# Object Creation in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Is there a difference between creating an object like this

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

or

```
List<string> list = new();
```

in .NET 6?
Both create a list but are there any benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: No, there is no difference in what is compiled.

Comment: The generated IL is identical https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugCwDcOyAzEagQMIEDeOBbRNyJBAsgBQBKZq3aiAbgEMATgQhgAzsAIBeAgDsApgHcCAGQXAAPMTwA+QRWyjR+xcfRnZBuqs1aLI6wU8EAvjl8gA=== so it boils down to style preference

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between those two. The second one is called [target-typed `new` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) and was introduced with C# 9 (so it was introduced before .NET 6 - with .NET 5). And both are compiled into the same - check out the desugared version using [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWA3AhgJ0QBsBLAZwBdEBeRAOwFMB3RAGTPIB4V4A+ACgCUmGGwpcIvIuwjU6TQcJIUAdAEEAJur4AibUNhLyENZp17hsIA).

As for benefits - both [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) and target-typed `new` expressions have the same goal - to reduce size of code, for local variables it is matter of preference which to use, but there are scenarios when only one can be used, for example for properties/fields you can't use `var` but can use `new`:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> Dictionary = new();
}
```

While for results of method invocation you can use only `var`:

```cs
var s = GetString();
```

Comment: Cant I write string s = GetString() (assuming it returns a string)? Do you mean it as a .Net convention

Comment: @user19187727 yes, you can. It is one of approaches when to use `var` - when type is evident, and when it is not - specify type explicitly (some code style tools have a setting for it)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the object creation. More info over using 'var' you can find [here](https://intellitect.com/blog/when-to-use-and-not-use-var-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

Name of this feature is `Type Inference`, F# and FP languages have way more strong implementation of this

It helps you to use static typed languages as dynamic typed, write only code, logic without thinking about types and Compiler will do their job, and infer all types at compile time

For your concrete sample, here is some example

1. When you write chain of fluent api and don't exact final type

   var result = data.Select()
2. When you pass params

   Method(new())